# How to set a 2 dimensional array as a property?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

I want to set a 2 dimensional array as a property but I keep getting multiple errors when I try.

This is what I just tried. The comments are the errors.

```
Dim _magnitude(,) As Integer
Public Property magnitude() As Integer
    Get
        Return Me._magnitude 'Value of type '2-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'Integer'
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Me._magnitude = value 'Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '2-dimensional array of Integer'
    End Set
End Property
```

I'm sure the answer is really obvious, I'm new to vb.net.

Comment: `Public Property magnitude As Integer(,)` but there is probably a better way to store that

Comment: Thanks! What's the better way?

Comment: that depends on what it is and how it is used, stored, referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type `Integer(,)` for the property and setter parameter:

```
Dim _magnitude(,) As Integer
Public Property magnitude As Integer(,)
    Get
        Return Me._magnitude
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer(,))
        Me._magnitude = value
    End Set
End Property
```